# Destructor in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was wondering what would happen in such a class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<int> iVector;
    void Worker()
    {
        //Lots of stuff done with iVector
        //adding, removing elements, etc.
    }
}
```

Let's say I create a thread (invoked by one of the class member functions) that uses iVector and modifies it. Besides this worker, none of the other member functions of the class reads or modifies this std::vector.

Everything seems fine as worker thread is the only one using iVector.

But what would happen when one instance of the object is destroyed? Even if the object is destroyed after the worker thread is finished, destructor for iVector would be invoked from the main thread. Would this lead to undefined behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: If the lifetime of the object is longer than the thread or any other use of the object, then there is no UB.

Comment: By the way, if the vector is only use by the thread and nowhere else, why not have it as a local variable inside the thread? Then you also don't have to worry about things like this.

Comment: The lifetime of the object is no longer by the thread. But why is it fine to destroy the vector in thread A when it is modified in thread B (worker thread)?

Comment: Actually the whole implementation is more complex than this. It would be difficult to make it a local variable. I just simplified it for the question.

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood you. Is the object (and therefore the vector) used by multiple threads? Then the lifetime must greater or equal to *all* threads that use it.

Comment: The vector is only used by the worker thread. Its lifetime is greater than the thread that uses it. But I still cannot see why destroying this vector in the main thread (as the object is created in the main thread) wouldn't lead to UB after it is modified in worker thread.

Comment: The vector is used by whatever thread touches its data or methods. If the main thread runs the destructor, then the vector is used by the main thread too. You have to make sure there are no data races between worker and main threads. Other than that, there's no reason for UB.

Comment: Make sure the worker threads are all joined before destructing the MyClass object

Comment: @sapito There is only one address space inside a process.  ALL threads have access to ALL memory in the process. So, the fact that the vector is created and destroyed in the main thread is *irrelevant*. There is no reason that *other* threads can't touch the same vector while it is alive (as long as you provide adequate and safe cross-thread access to it, which it sounds like you are in this example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest running a `std::join` (or your library equivalent) on the thread in the destructor. This will ensure the thread is properly finished and synchronized before the vector destructor runs. This is important as the vector's lifetime must exceed the thread using it.

The C++11 standard and presumably later ones state in 30.3.1.5:

> 5: Synchronization: The completion of the thread represented by *this
>   synchronizes with (1.10) the corresponding successful join() return. [
>   Note: Operations on *this are not synchronized. — end note ]

Now we have to examine 1.10 for more detail, first this section states:

> 3: The value of an object visible to a thread T at a particular point
>   is the initial value of the object, a value assigned to the object by
>   T, or a value assigned to the object by another thread, according to
>   the rules below.

Honestly, this is difficult to parse, it does not specify exactly what kind of synchronization join offers and seems to imply it synchronizes only the thread itself and not data it has accessed. Therefore I would go the safe route and run `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire)` after join in the main thread, and `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` in the child thread just before it finishes which should guarantee full happens before semantics and no UB.

Comment: I am already calling std::join on the thread in the destructor of MyClass. But I had no idea std::join prevents the calling thread from missing changes the worker thread did :)

Comment: @sapito Let me read my C++ standard quick and then I will see if this is definately safe

Comment: @sapito I have updated my answer with some standard quotes and a method of achieving additional safety if you are not confident join alone is enough. Honestly I cant parse from the standard if join only synchronizes the threads termination itself, or also data the thread was using. Nor does it say what kind of synchronization semantics it offers.. Therefore to be safe you can use the fence route.

Comment: I don't think fences are required in presence of `join` because of [1.10.1.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-9) (An evaluation A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if A synchronizes with B) and `join` does  synchronize

Comment: @LukaRahne what worried me is the "Note: Operations on *this are not synchronized. — end note " part, do you have any idea what that is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

If an execution thread is using the `ivector` class member, and another thread destroys the object with this class member, the continued use of the `ivector` class member results in undefined behavior.

> Even if the object is destroyed after the worker thread is finished,
>   destructor for iVector would be invoked from the main thread. Would
>   this lead to undefined behavior?

No. As you've described, this situation is not undefined behavior. The C++ standard does not require an object to be destroyed by the same execution thread that created the object. It's fine for one execution thread to grow, resize the vector, then go away or stop using the vector, and then a different execution thread destroy the entire object.

Comment: Even if it is not part of my original question, it would be nice to know how the destructor gets synchronized with the changes made by other thread (in contrast to a member function). BTW, what I am talking about is: Thread A creates and destroys the std::vector (but never modifies or reads it), Thread B modifies and reads it.

Comment: This "synchronization" is not related to the act of invoking the destructor. The C++ standard has an entire boring, lengthy section that fleshes out the formal specification for "sequencing", that is when all "changes" in one executed thread become visible in another thread. Destroying an object must be sequenced in a manner that all references to the object from other threads must be sequenced before whichever thread that destroys the object actually does it. It's up to the multithreaded code to properly sequence itself. An object's destructor is not responsible for that.