# Proper destruction of object in a multi threaded environment

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I inherited a multi-threaded legacy code that I think is not destroying the object correctly.

```
class A
{
private:
    TCCState *b; // TCCState is struct from third party library
public:
    static A func1();
    ~A();
};

std::unique_ptr<A> A::func1()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> res(new A());
    int ret = gen_tcc_context(res); // gen_tcc_context is library function
    return res; // this res is used as std::unique_ptr<A> temp(std::move(A::func1())); and then properly destroyed 
}

A::~A()
{
    if (b != nullptr){// Is this necessary? If yes, should I used a lock_guard for this code? 
        tcc_delete(b);// tcc_delete is a library function. This raises an exception - Assertion failed: ("Invalid file descriptor. File possibly closed by a different thread",0)
    }
}
```

It looks like the code fragment in destructor is trying to close something that is already closed. Is the code fragment in the destructor really necessary? If yes, does using lock-guard safe?

Comment: In the actual code, do the class follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, since `func1()` is declared as returning an `A` object in the class declaration but is declared as returning a `std::unique_ptr<A>` in its definition.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would not free things correctly. There is only 1 `A` object being allocated, and it is destructed only once, and it deletes its tcc resource when destructed. The fact that the `A` object is moved around a few `unique_ptr` objects doesn't change that.  The `A` object is not destructed until the final `unique_ptr` is destructed. But, what does any of this have to do with multi-threading?  There is no threading in this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destructor in a multithreaded environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925092/destructor-in-a-multithreaded-environment)

Comment: You can put `TCCState` in a `std::unique_ptr<TCCState, TCCStateDeleter>` if you define your own *deleter*.

Comment: Does `tcc_delete()` require that it be called from the same thread that created b in the first place?  If so, and if you passed your `std::unique_ptr` object to a different thread after `func1()` returned it, that might explain the exception you get.

Comment: Why does it look like it's closing something that's already closed?

Answer (score 1):

When object is ready to be destroyed this means that only current thread is using it. If this is not true than life time management of the object is invalid. So bottom line destructor do not require synchronization.

Off topic:
you do not need destructor at all if you define pointer properly:

```
class TCCState_deleter {
public:
    void operator()(TCCState *b) {
         tcc_delete(b);
    }
};

class A
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<TCCState, TCCState_deleter> b;
public:
    static A func1();
};
```